# Como mostrar un elemento de un JSON de acuerdo a un ID con REACT

Tags: json, reactjs

soy nuevo con React y quisiera me ayuden a realizar esto, actualmente tengo una tabla que muestra los datos de los cursos, pero quisiera que en vez del ID del profesor muestre su nombre, tengo 2 json con esos datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi tengo mi codigo en React que muestra los cursos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguien pueda hecharme una mano con esto.
Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, copia/pega el código para la otra en vez de poner pantallazos. Saludos

Comment: Ok, lo tomare en cuenta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

casi lo tienes, te falta buscar en el array de profesores al que coincida con el id que tienes.

te pongo un ejemplo:

```
<td>{professors.find(p => p.id === professorId).name}</td>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya me has dado una idea, lo intentare, cualquier cosa te comento. Saludos

Comment: Si te ha servido, te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como válida, muchas gracias.

Comment: Gracias me sirvo. Saludos.